# YAML validation on API plaftform

Tags: api-platform.com

I use API platform with YAML instead of Annotations. It's very easy to add validation constraint on Annotation but how add constraint in YAML. In the doc in Validation chapter I don't find. https://api-platform.com/docs/core/validation/#validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Platform uses the constraint validator from Symfony, you can refer to the [symfony constraints documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html).

For example, using the Product sample from API platform with [NotBlank constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html) you should have:

```
# config/validator/validation.yaml
App\Entity\Product:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

Comment: I don't knowed  that Api platform used symfony validator thx